# How to show user email for custom login form in meteor

Tags: authentication, meteor

Hi i'm trying to create a custom login form in meteor that functions similarly to the default provided. I want to show my users' email address if they are signed in and show the login buttons if they're not. so far i have

```
{{#if currentUser}}
    {{displayName}}
 {{/else}}
    <button>Login</button>
 {{/if}
```

but this isn't working. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have account packages added, `currentUser` helper should work and you should only add helper that looks like

```
displayName: function(){
return Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
}
```

## Edit

Oh I know where you have a mistake, it should be `{{else}}` not `{{/else}}`

Comment: thank you very much! this worked perfectly. just a quick question on security - is it better if i put this code in a server side method and call it from there? thanks

Comment: You mean displayName helpers? Meteor.user() is visible to client, so there is no need to use server side calls, use calls mostly for operations with database(but I would rather suggest making good allows).